# Where can I find a good overview of all the different types of Facebook native pages/profiles that are currently active?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

Over time Facebook has been evolving their system of pages and profiles.

Some of these profiles/pages remain as old versions as their users/moderators forget to upgrade them as the changes are released.

I've inherited as small village of Facebook Profiles and Pages which I have been told to convert to the latest before March 30th when the new Timeline version of the Business pages come out.

So I was wondering if anyone knew where I could find an overview of the old types of Facebook pages / profiles (to recognize them by version name and image) so that I can convert the existing mishmash of pages into a standardized type before the deadline.

P.S. I have already seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5058344/facebook-how-to-find-different-types-of-facebook-pages) but it appears to link to documentation which is no longer relevant, and only covers the graph API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Local Business:

- Other Business
- Automotive
- Automotive Dealer / Vehicle Service
- Banking and Financial Service
- Bar
- Cafe
- Club
- Convention Center and Sports Complex
- Education
- Event Planning Service
- Grocery
- Health and Beauty
- Home Service
- Hotel / Lodging
- Library / Public Building
- Medical Service
- Museum / Attraction
- Park
- Pets
- Professional Service
- Real Estate
- Religious Center
- Restaurant
- Store
- Technology and Telecommunications Service
- Travel Service

Brand, Product, or Organization:

- Products
- Airline / Ship / Train Station
- Communications
- Consumer Product
- Fashion
- Film
- Financial Service
- Food and Beverage
- Game
- Government
- Home Living
- Hotel / Lodging
- Non-Profit
- Online Store
- Pharmaceutical
- Professional Service
- Religious Organization
- Rental Cars
- Retail
- Sports / Athletics
- TV Show
- Technology Product / Service
- Travel
- Website

Artist, Band, or Public Figure:

- Other Public Figure
- Actor
- Athlete
- Band
- Comedian
- Critic
- Government Official
- Model
- Musician
- Politician
- Sports Team
- Visual Artist
- Writer

<sub>This was based on just browsing old pictures of create pages.php page</sub>